# laravel events, are they executing synchronously?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

basically what I want to do is use a [special token auto login](https://github.com/dwightwatson/autologin)

but: only for a subset of pages. Say, commenting is ok with the token login. Changing credit card information and purchasing items is not ok with the token login.

So I want to store a boolean `token_login` on the `users` table.

On each login i set the `token_login` to false using the event handler

```
class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    protected $listen = [
      'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => [PostLoginListener::class],
    ];
```

When a true token login is performed, I set it to true.

So I expect the event to get called -> token_login = false

then code keeps running, setting token_login = true in case of the actual autologin.

Now this requires that the event actually always fires synchronously and always before the other code. Is that the case?

Comment: I don't know if you could see this as an answer, but events are fired from with `fireEvent` methods e.g. https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1473

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As long as your `PostLoginListener` does not implement the `Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue` interface, your event will be processed synchronously.

Comment: Note: the events don't actually process. The event just says "this thing has happened and here is some data related to it". So, the concept of an asynchronous or queued event is asking the wrong question. It is the listeners that may *process the event* which, may run synchronously or be queued. Just added this to highlight the idea behind your answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP is a synchronous language (If you're not using HHVM or Hack), the events are always fired in the same order. So you can test whether or not this event fires before the other, and then go further from that.

Edit:
The way Laravel fires the events is largely based on the order in which your ServiceProvider array is stored inside `config/app.php`.